# Plotting SVM Linear Separator in R

Tags: r, plot, machine-learning, svm

I'm trying to plot the 2-dimensional hyperplanes (lines) separating a 3-class problem with *e1071*'s svm. I used the *default* method (so there is no formula involved) like so:

```
library('e1071')
## S3 method for class 'default':
machine <- svm(x, y, kernel="linear")
```

I cannot seem to plot it by using the `plot.svm` method:

```
plot(machine, x)
Error in plot.svm(machine, x) : missing formula.
```

But I did not use the *formula* method, I used the *default* one, and if I pass `'~'` or `'~.'` as a formula argument it'll complain about the matrix `x` not being a `data.frame`.

- Is there a way of plotting the fitted separator/s for the 2D problem while using the *default* method?
- How may I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post a reproducible example, with a small data frame? Thanks.

Comment: `x <- prcomp(iris[,1:4])$x[,1:2]` and `y <- iris[,5]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that although `svm()` allows you to specify your input using either the default or formula method, `plot.svm()` only allows a formula method. Also, by only giving `x` to `plot.svm()`, you are not giving it all the info it needs. It also needs `y`.

Try this:

```
library(e1071)

x <- prcomp(iris[,1:4])$x[,1:2]
y <- iris[,5]

df <- data.frame(cbind(x[],y[]))

machine <- svm(y ~ PC1 + PC2, data=df)
plot(machine, data=df)
```

[image: svmplot]

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your `x` has more than two feature-variables or columns.
Since `plot.svm()` plots only 2-Dimensions at a time, you need to specify these dimensions explicitly by providing a formula argument.

```
Ex:-  ## more than two variables: fix 2 dimensions

data(iris)
m2 <- svm(Species~., data = iris)
plot(m2, iris, Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length,slice = list(Sepal.Width = 3, Sepal.Length = 4))
```

In cases where the data-frames has only two dimensions by default, you can ignore the formula argument.

```
Ex:- ## a simple example 

data(cats, package = "MASS")
m <- svm(Sex~., data = cats)
plot(m, cats)
```

These details can be found at `plot.svm()` documentation here https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/e1071/versions/1.7-3/topics/plot.svm